# I am trying to create a GUI based client-server chat application, when running it locally the connection is made successfully but not publicly

Tags: python, sockets, tkinter, client-server

error shown is as follows:
A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond.

Comment: Check if the firewalls on both ends are configured correctly. For better answers show the relevant code as properly formatted text in the question.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Did you bind the *public IP address* in the server side? Otherwise clients cannot connect to it.